# Novice issue of this jQuery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to jQuery, and I want this code to show an alert box when the button is pressed.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked.");
});
</script>
<button>Button</button>
```

I try it, and nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: When the script is executed, the button does not yet exist in the DOM. Either wait for the DOM to be ready, or move the script after the button.

Comment: Put the `<script>` after the `<button>` if you want it to exist and run immediately.

Answer (score 6):

In jQuery when event handlers are added, you need to make sure that the element is already loaded to the dom else jQuery selector will not return the element so the event handler will not get registered.

The solution is to use the dom ready event handler which will get triggered once the initial dom loading is completed meaning all the elements in the pages is loaded into the dom, it is the safest place to add the event handlers.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked.");
    });
})
```

As @zzzzBov noted below, it is a short cut for using the lengthy document ready handler

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked.");
    });
})
```

Comment: A note about what makes this answer special, the aliasing shorthand for `document.ready` is being used, so this code will continue to work, even if `$.noConflict()` is called.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, when your code executes, the button has not been loaded so it does not attach the click handler to anything, therefore you need to wrap your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so that there is for sure a DOM element to attach your handler to, so your code becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked.");
    });
});
```

See **[the documentation on $(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**.

Comment: Thanks. I feel really dumb now.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in `ready` event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling jQuery to add the click handler before you're `<button>` is declared, so jQuery doesn't find it. Either move the `<button>` to the top of your snippet, or use a DOM ready function to delay your script execution until the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running that script before the button exists, put it after instead:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked.");
});
</script>
```